# Why this code can create a list of Binary number?

Tags: python

Here is the code:

```
def bin_list(bit_len):
    list_len = 2 ** bit_len
    return ['{0:0{1}b}'.format(i, bit_len) for i in range(list_len)]

print(bin_list(3))
```

Output:

```
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

So this code can create a binary number list.

My main problem is:

```
'{0:0{1}b}'.format(i, bit_len)
```

I have no idea what this means. Is it a regex or something?

Comment: It converts `i` to binary representation, then pads the string with zeroes. Here `bit_len` will be the minimum field width. https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the python [format string documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings)

The value before the `:` specifies the field to format (in this case, 0, so the first param)

```
'{0}'.format(2) == '2'
```

The value after the colon specifies the format. And it gets fancy here. First the `b` specifies binary rendering

```
'{0:b}'.format(2) == '10'
```

Then you can specify a minimum width, which here is taken from the second parameter:

```
'{0:5b}'.format(2) == '   10'
'{0:{1}b}'.format(2, 5) == '   10'
```

And lastly you can add a 0 before the width to say the padding should be `0`s and not spaces:

```
'{0:05b}'.format(2) == '00010'
'{0:0{1}b}'.format(2, 5) == '00010'
```

Comment: This really helps! Thank you! :)